# Sorting array doesn't work when array isn't full

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've created a few Insertion, selection and bubble sorts. They seem to work when the object array is full but when I make the array to have 5 and only fill it with 3, it errors when I sort. Here is my sort code.

```
public class CityList {
    private City[] city;
    private Integer numberOfCities;

    public CityList (Integer cityListSize){
        this.city=new City[cityListSize];
        this.numberOfCities=0;
    }

    public void addCity(String city){
        this.city[this.numberOfCities]=new City(city);
        this.numberOfCities++;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String cityDetails=new String();
        if (this.numberOfCities!=0){
            cityDetails+=String.format("%-15s\n","CITY");
            for(Integer i=0;i<this.numberOfCities;i++)
            cityDetails+=this.city[i]+"\n";
        }
        else
            cityDetails+="City list is empty";
        return cityDetails;
    }

    public void sort(){
        int j, i;  
        for(i =1; i < city.length; i++){    
            City temp = city[i];           
            j = i;                
            while((j>0) && ((city[j -1].getCity().compareTo(temp.getCity()))>0)){               
                city[j] = city[j-1];
                --j; 
            }    
            city[j] = temp;    
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: For a more general approach, you may want to ignore null objects rather than assume that null objects only occur at the end of an array. One way to do this is to pack the array so that the array ends up with all non-null objects at the start followed by null objects at the end. I think this is how Java internal sorts operate.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition in the for loop `i < city.length && city[i] != null` to stop if the array is not full. Also arrays in java are 0-based i.e., the first element is `city[0]` not `city[1]`

Comment: I want it to sort the array even if it isn't full.

Comment: I understand the first element is index[0]... That is why I have j-1 comparing to i

Comment: @Stefza manage the case when is null in `compareTo()` function to defined the order it must follow

Comment: I've found out what im doing wrong. Ive looped through the array.length and not the elements within the array.

Comment: The idea is that `j` goes from 0... i - 1 in every iteration, so `city[i] == null` marks the end of your array

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying @Aimee, sorry I misread what you were saying. I though you were saying not to do the sort if city[i] == null. So I can break out the loop when city[i] == null.

Comment: I found the silly mistake. I shouldn't be looping the Array.Length. I should be using numberOfCities.